# How to export a Google Form on a WordPress Site to a Google Spreadsheet using if/then?

Tags: wordpress, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had not thought that my question would be complicated, but I can't find the answer no matter how hard I look. I may not just be phrasing the question correctly, in which case, I would be most grateful to the link for what I'm trying to do.

So, a live-action RPG that I'm on staff for has been running for nigh on these many years, in one single location. Now, we're splitting into two locations, and trying to update all our systems and processes to accommodate two separate groups of players.

That above paragraph may not have meant anything to you. It's cool!

Basically, there are two groups of users, with some crossover. Users fill out forms on the website (WordPress, self-hosted), which export to a shared Google Spreadsheet. Admins need access to all the responses, though with an easy way to determine which responses are the ones they are directly responsible for (i.e, exporting to separate pages on the same spreadsheet).

Anyway, I've inherited a lot of the old setup, and, as luck would have it, the dude formerly in charge of all this has taken a break from the game. So I'm trying to solve this without pestering him, if I can help it.

So, the problem.

What I would like to do is have a question at the top of the form: Do you play in Location A or Location B?  If you answer Location A, your responses then export to the page in the spreadsheet labeled for the people in charge of Location A; if you answer Location B, same thing. The pseudocode for what I want is, "If Player selects Location==A, form answers export to LocationA_SpreadsheetPage on Google Spreadsheet; elseif Player selects Location==B, form answers export to LocationB_SpreadsheetPage on Google Spreadsheet."

There are three forms I need to have export to six different pages on the same spreadsheet, based on whether the user selects radial button A or radial button B. I feel sure as though Google and WordPress must somehow have this capability, but I'm not using the right search terms to find the necessary tutorials.

Thank you so much in advance, anyone with the answer to this question!

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet where the form stores the answers you can add a script and configure it to be executed as a "OnFormSubmit" trigger.
When someone fill the form and sends the request, the trigger will execute the function and then you can catch the values of the response. 
In that same Spreadsheet you can have other sheets, and inside the code you can decide to add the information to the respective sheet.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) you can find information about triggers in apps script.

For this case you would need to use the property "values" of the event object.

```
function Event(e)
{
  var values = e.values;

}
```

This property will give you the array of the answers. the first object in the array is the date so you can check for the second element.

Hope this helps.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) is the documentation on how to configure the events. A simple way to do it is to click on the "clocl" button that is on the left of the "run" button.